# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SSLContext

Tags: java, security, database-connection

I am developing a standalone java application which will be packaged as a jar file (OSGi plugin) and going to be run in a EAR which is deployed on `Jboss AS 7.1` When I try to connect to `Microsoft SQLServer 10` using `JDBC type 4` driver(sqljdbc4.jar) I am getting the following `Exception`.

```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish   
   a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption.   
   Error: "class configured for SSLContext:  
  sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context not a SSLContext".

    Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for 
     SSLContext:  sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context not a SSLContext

  C14:30:34,169 ERROR [stderr] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 13)            
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.checkSuperClass(GetInstance.java:258).
```

**Note:** The application runs fine in eclipse. But after making it as a jar and deployed into Jboss It is throwing the exception

My jar directory structure

```
 MYApp
 |
 |src
  |  
  |   
  | 
   META-INF
   |
    lib
     | 
       sqljdbc4.jar
       rt.jar
       jsse.jar
```

Comment: What Java versions you're using for Eclipse and JBoss?

Comment: Jdk 1.7 ,Eclipse-Indigo  and JBoss 1.7 @Jk1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove java related jars from lib directory in your case `rt.jar` and `jsse.jar` and add `xmlbeans.jar, xbean.jar, xml-apis` to your library.